# How to create dynamic two dimensional element

Tags: angular

I know how to use `ngFor` to create multiple element.

```
// component's data
items = [
    {'name': 'Item 1'},
    {'name': 'Item 2'},
    {'name': 'Item 3'},
    {'name': 'Item 4'},
    {'name': 'Item 5'},
    {'name': 'Item 6'},
];
....
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div class="col">
    <label><input type="radio">{{item.name}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
....
```

But today I want to create each 3 elements for a group with angular2.

```
....
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <label><input type="radio">Item 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <label><input type="radio">Item 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <label><input type="radio">Item 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <label><input type="radio">Item 4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <label><input type="radio">Item 5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <label><input type="radio">Item 6</label>
  </div>
</div>
....
```

I don't want to modify my array structure. How can do it? Can I move out `ngFor` element? Thanks your help.

Comment: is to ok to modify the `items` array

Comment: If I don't want to modify it. Can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a pipe that groups the elements first into sub-arrays along the lines:

```
@Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(arr: [], groups: number): any {
    return arr.reduce((res, item) => {
      if (res.length === 0 || (res[res.length - 1] && res[res.length - 1].length === groups)) {
        res.push([]);
      }
      res[res.length - 1].push(item);
      return res;
    }, []);
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let group of items | groupBy:3">
  <div class="col" *ngFor="let item of group">
    <label><input type="radio">{{item.name}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course this might affect performance, but is readable, flexible and respects your desire to not change the initial data structure - it will only be transformed by the pipe while rendering and it's transparent.

Don't forget to register your pipe in your module, e.g. via the `declarations` section.

Note: the pipe code can probably be improved, it's just a raw implementation.

Comment: Thanks your reply. I have thought of that. But I feel strange. I thought I can move out `ngFor` from dom element, but I can't find it.

Comment: @lighter I'm not sure what you mean by `move out ngFor from dom element`

Comment: For example. `<?php foreach ($items as $index => $item); if ($index % 3 === 0)?><div class="row">....`.

Comment: `{{ngFor="let item of items"}} <div class="row">...`

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution but you can do something like this

```
<div class="row" >
  <div class="col" *ngFor="let item of items" [ngIf]="$index < 3">
    <label><input type="radio">{{item.name}}</label>
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"  *ngFor="let item of items" [ngIf]="$index >= 3">
    <label><input type="radio">{{item.name}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank your answer. But I think if I have more datas, my code will become ugly.

Comment: yeah best solution is to use a pipe